# Visual Studio 2022 - Char retornando Inteiro Negativo para caractere ã

Tags: c++

Estou utilizando Visual Studio Community 2022 em ambiente Windows 10.
No código abaixo, quando digito "João é um cara legal." apresenta erro quando lê o caractere "ã". Debugando o programa, verifiquei cin.get(ch) está armazenando -29 sendo que deveria ser 198 na tabela ASCII. Alguém teria a explicação do porque está retornando número negativo? Obrigado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1252 > nul");
    cout << "Entre com o texto para analise (@ para sair):\n";
    int brancos = 0, digitos = 0, chars = 0, pont = 0, outros = 0;
    char ch;

    cin.get(ch);       // lê o primeiro caractere
    while (ch != '@')  // testa o caractere sentinela
    {
        if (isalpha(ch)) chars++;         // é uma letra do alfabeto? 
        else if (isspace(ch)) brancos++;  // é um caractere de espaço?
        else if (isdigit(ch)) digitos++;  // é um dígito?
        else if (ispunct(ch)) pont++;     // é uma pontuação?
        else outros++;
        cin.get(ch);   // lê o próximo caractere
    }

    cout << chars << " letras, " << digitos << " digitos " << brancos << " espacos, "
        << pont << " pontuacoes e " << outros << " outros.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uma observação. O valor da tabela ASCII só vale se o texto estiver em ASCII. Dê uma olhada se o texto não está em UTF-8, que pode ser um complicador a mais no seu código.

Comment: Tentou executar a rotina?

Comment: Como já dito pelo colega Leonardo na resposta abaixo, você usou um tipo que não pode ser maior que 127. Ao atribuir um valor maior, teve um overflow. Se mudar o tipo para unsigned, a faixa passa a ser de 0 a 255. Outra coisa, `ã` não faz parte da tabela ASCII. todos maiores que 127 são tabelas estendidas. (e o negativo obtido e o positivo que esperava são o mesmo byte, com representações diferentes)

Answer (score 1):

O tipo `char` possui apenas 1 byte - ou seja, ele varia de `-128` até `127`. Como o valor que tu atribuiste (`ã`) [não consta nos 127 valores da tabela ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii), ele não tem associação entre os positivos.

Todavia, existe a [tabela extendida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII), que pode ser usado para `unsigned char` - que varia de 0 a 255. No teu caso, tu atribuiste um valor pertencente apenas à tabela extendida para um `char`. A atribuição deu "overflow" (estouro do limite máximo do valor), fazendo o char ser negativo.

Comment: Eu não atribui o valor. Foi a conversão char do caractere "ã".

Comment: Não entendi o comentário - `cin.get(ch);` atribui o valor da entrada à variável `ch`. Se não tivesse atribuido um valor à variável, seria comportamento indefinido (iria pegar o lixo da memória)

Comment: Tentou executar a rotina escrevendo [João é um cara legal.]?

Comment: @CidGianni não está tendo nenhuma conversão (o byte é gravado pelo cin da mesma forma), você usou um tipo onde não cabe a faixa de valores que espera, então a faixa de valores é diferente do que imaginava ao exibir. Se fizer o que o Leonardo respondeu aqui, o resultado cairá na faixa adequada.